# How to extract a string after and before a specific word using Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract a string after `opResult` and before another string (word+ '=')

For example:

> testest=false    opResult=Critical extension not supported    random=abc srcPort=10

So I should extract out `Critical extension not supported`, before the next word with an equals sign.

Also, it should also work if there is no other string at the back, meaning I should get the same result with the below example.

> typesOnly=false    opResult=Critical extension not supported

The regular expression I have currently extracted everything before the last '=' sign.

```
opResult=(\S.*)(\s\w+=)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try matching/extracting using the following pattern:

```
.*opResult=(.*?)(?:\\s*\\S+=.*|$)
```

The trick here is in being able to articulate when the next key begins, and then to not extract it.

```
String line = "testest=false opResult=Critical extension not supported random=abc srcPort=10";
String pattern = ".*opResult=(.*?)(?:\\s*\\S+=.*|$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Critical extension not supported
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: It only works if there are string at the back but it should also work if there is no string at the back.

Comment: I just updated to cover the case where `opResult` is the final key in the string.  Other than this, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should work with positive lookbehind and positive lookahead and a lazy quantifier for the text in between

```
(?<=opResult=).*?(?=\s*\S*=)
```

You can see the results on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B9zRIZ/4).

Comment: it shouldn't grab the random word, should only get 'Critical extension not supported'

Comment: @Kaycee Didn't see it, but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

We need to find text after 'opResult=' before the next blankspace(\s)word(\w+) followed by an equals sign (?==) and whatever follows (.*)

Pattern becomes

```
.*opResult=([\w|\s]+)(\s\w+(?==).*)
```

Here's the link to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B9zRIZ/3)